# LinkedIn share button removing the QueryString from the URL

Tags: html, share, linkedin-api, query-string

**Trying to** create a share to LinkedIn button which points to a page with querystring at the end.

1. As you can see, the code contains the URL:

   - `https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab=summary`
2. but upon going to the LinkedIn site, the URL becomes:

   - `https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab`
3. the **querystring** part is removed, the question: Is there anyway to go around this issue?

```css
a i {color:#000}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab=summary">
<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:36px"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2020** : Linkedin has updated its sharing url , so query parameters **not supported** in URL

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=URL_HERE
```

**OLD Answer :**

here is working demo :

> convert your **=** to **%3D**

`tab%3Dsummary`

here is [link](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) to encode your character .

```css
a i {color:#000}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab%3Dsummary">
<i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" style="font-size:36px"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you add a source/reference link for query parameters no longer being supported by LinkedIn? I can't find anything on Google.

Comment: The query parameters are still supported as of today, just need to encode `=` to `%3D` as written in the answer.

Comment: I've tried using %3D, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This **DOES** work...

This only problem in the original question is the "=" at the very end. Let me explain...

This is LinkedIn's base URL and you just add the URL of what you would like to share on to the end of it. The URL of the page you're sharing can not contain an "=", so you just have to replace any "=" (from your share URL, not the base URL) with a "%3D".

This part is fine:
`https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=`

This part can not have a "=". Use "%3D" in its place:
`https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab%3Dsummary`

Fixed:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab%3Dsummary">
```

Example on my CodePen: https://codepen.io/ckschmieder/pen/PoNmwya

Comment: Your answer is correct but same as the accepted answer

Comment: That doesn't work anymore, going to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757883/akber-iqbal?tab%3Dsummary removes the query parameter.

Comment: Escape the question mark with %3F

Example: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://domain.dd%3Futm_campaign%3Dlorem&utm_source%3Dipsum